# Passing a batch file to powershell that expects user input in the same console

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I execute a batch file from powershell with

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath $PathToBatchFile $SomeArguments
```

This opens a new cmd window in which a Y/N question has to be answered by pressing Y or N, before a build is executed. When it is finished the console window closes. However when I add the `-NoNewWindow` flag the script starts but seems to wait indefinitly. So this hangs

```
Start-Process -Wait -NoNewWindow -FilePath $PathToBatchFile $SomeArguments
```

My guess is that it waits for the input (notably the message requesting input is not shown in the ps terminal). Maybe stdio has to be attached to the ps session? Maybe I am missing something very obvious?
Any suggestions? I know it's nothing crucial but it does bother me.

Edit:

Clarification: I do not want to programmatically provide the input. Instead I want to be able to interactively input (in the same powershell console) the required input, as well as see the batch script's output.
So the question is perhaps more correctly stated as how to attach the std input/output of a child cmd in the same powershell console.

Edit:

Works in the Powershell console, NOT in the ISE. Any solution to ISE would be welcome. Need to check for myself first though.

Comment: Unless you try to pass the `Y` input to your process how is it supposed to take the input? Your question does not indicate that you have researched or made any attempt at sending an input. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49978573/edit) to show us the batch file content, adding what you've tried, and explain how it failed.

Comment: Are you sure you are using a PowerShell console as the batch file will run in the same window? This is not the case for PowerShell ISE, maybe you are using PowerShell ISE...

Comment: That's it. Sorry should have checked that myself. Any idea how to get this behaviour in the ISE?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RedirectStandardInput` parameter to provide the response to the prompt. The following sends 'Y' to the batch file.

```
"Y" | Out-File -FilePath input.txt 
start-process -FilePath $PathToBatchFile -Wait -RedirectStandardInput "input.txt" -NoNewWindow
```